# "Unidentified USB Device" on Win CE 6.0

Tags: usb, windows-ce, driver

Quite a while I am struggling with a problem regarding the installation of certain USB device driver in Windows CE 6.0.

The device is some kind of Digital and Analog IO device that connects to the USB port.
It is the LabJack U3.

I followed all instruction and put the driver (labjackusb.dll) and coresponding registry entries into the Windows CE image but the device is not detected correctly.

On every boot up a small Message box came up with the Title "Unidentified USB Device"
and the message "Enter the name of the driver for this USB device:"

Whatever name I put into it want work. I tried the name of the dll. Some title in from the registry and so on but never succedes.

The driver does not work nor the device.

The customer support can not help me so I am asking here somebody to help me at least
with a steps to follow to try to find a solution.

Why the OS does not matches the USB device with the corresponding driver?
I checked everything one million times and everything is in place.

Answer (score 1):

There are a load of reasons this might fail.  First:

- Is the driver definitely a *Windows CE* driver?
- Is it built for CE 6.0 (not 5.0 or something else)?
- Is it built for the same processor architecture you have?

The way to really debug this is to hook up KITL, put in a debug version of device.exe and see what the device managet is actually doing when you plug in the device.  A way better and way more reliable mechanism than just trying to guess.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the reply. The driver is supposed to work from Win CE to Win CE 5.0. It is never tested by the supplier on Win CE 6.0 but there are customers that are using it with no problem. About the processor architecture I need to check. When I enable KITL the main screen turns black so I need to look what is happening only on COM1. In the end you suggests to use KITL ? OK I will try. The error mentioned comes up at boot phase of the OS. Before any application start.

Comment: Do you know if the Win CE starts the driver before its real use from some custom application or is it started when the OS detect some device on the USB port?

Comment: Detection and driver loading is done when the device is plugged in.